# Query for rootDSE tokenGroups comes out empty, should contain security groups for user

Tags: azure, active-directory

A little background:
I am trying to get synchronization of one of our development ADs to Azure Active Directory set up, using the Microsoft DirSync tool. The configuration fails, as the tool claims the AD account I am trying to use lacks membership of the "Enterprise Admins" group.

Digging into the root cause, I have been able to pinpoint that the code doing the check is querying the security groups like this:

```
public static void Repro(string userName, string password)
{
    string name = ADValidation.GetUsersForest(userName, password).Name;
    string path = string.Format("LDAP://{0}/", name);
    string rootDse = string.Format("{0}rootDSE", path);
    Console.WriteLine("Path: {0}", path);
    Console.WriteLine("RootDse: {0}", rootDse);
    const AuthenticationTypes authenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Signing | AuthenticationTypes.Secure;
    using (var entry = new DirectoryEntry(rootDse, userName, password, authenticationType))
    {
        entry.RefreshCache(new[] { "tokenGroups" });
        Console.WriteLine(entry.Properties["tokenGroups"].Count);
    }
}
```

Running this block on our corporate AD yields the list of security groups as expected:

```
Path: LDAP://SOMECORPDOMAIN.EXT/
RootDse: LDAP://SOMECORPDOMAIN.EXT/rootDSE
39
```

While running it on the development AD yields no groups:

```
Path: LDAP://SOMEDEVDOMAIN.EXT/
RootDse: LDAP://SOMEDEVDOMAIN.EXT/rootDSE
0
```

My knowledge of AD is quite limited - can anyone give me some pointers as to why the development AD would not return any security groups for the query?

Thanks in advance
/Michael

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to AD user permissions.